# if same id is present in two tables show edit button else show assign button in django

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views

Get all the employee profile  table id and check the id with employee process,if id matches show edit button in templates else show assign button.

Views.py

```
def Employee(request):
    emp = Emp_Profile.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    emptable = Emp_Profile.objects.values_list('id')
    print(emptable)
    empprocess = Emp_Process.objects.values_list('username_id').distinct()
    print(empprocess)
    obj = {}
    for i in range(len(empprocess)):
        obj[i] = empprocess[i]

    return render(request, 'employee.html',{'list' : emp,'empprocess':empprocess,'obj':obj})
```

templates

```
{% for list in list %}
{% if  obj != list.id %}
<td>
        <a href="/view_client_process/{{ list.id }}"><button
                class="btn btn-info">Edit</button></a>
    </td>
{% else %}
<h6>welcome</h6>
<td>
        <a href="/view_client_process/{{ list.id }}"><button
                class="btn btn-info">Assign</button></a>
    </td>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a set of `username_id`s and pass this to your template:

```
def Employee(request):
    empS = Emp_Profile.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    empprocess = set(Emp_Process.objects.values_list('username_id', flat=True).distinct())
    return render(request, 'employee.html', {'emps' : emps, 'empprocess': empprocess })
```

In the template, we can then make a membership check of the set:

```
{% for emp in emps %}
<td>
    {% if  emp.id not in empprocess %}
        <a href="/view_client_process/{{ emp.id }}"><button class="btn btn-info">Edit</button></a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="/view_client_process/{{ emp.id }}"><button class="btn btn-info">Assign</button></a>
    {% endif %}
</td>
{% endfor %}
```

> **Note**: you might want to rename your field <s>`username`</s> to `user` since a `ForeignKey` to a user is *not* the same as a username.

> **Note**: please use [**`{% url ... %}`** template tags [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) instead of performing URL processing yourself.